# text-stroke-width and text-stroke-color not working in gmail templete

Tags: html, css, html-email, stroke

I try to send mail using HTML all the CSS I use works but I set the stroke for the header working nicely in the browser but when i send mail i get black heading in email.

Text-shadows will not be displayed either! Any alternative way to display stroke for font?

```css
h3{
   font-family: sans-serif;
   margin: 40px 0;
   font-size: 40px;
   color:#fff;
   
   text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #9f5a57, 0px 0px 1px #9f5a57;
   
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: #9f5a57;
}
```

```html
<h3>LAUNCHING HAIR</h3>
```

I know image is the best option, even if CSS is not supported. But my problem is that the header is dynamic, so I can't put the image there.

I saw many solutions but I did not find any solution related to my issue.

Comment: Supported css properties are listed here - https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/reference/supported_css

Comment: @JonB any other way i can display stroke in email ?

Comment: It is not supported, so no

Comment: You must make it an image if you really want to show it. CHeck also https://www.caniemail.com/

Comment: @Nathan thanks for your replay, i know image is best option If CSS does not support. but my problem is heading will be dynamic so i can't put image there !

Comment: I'm not sure of your setup, but you might like to try, then, niftyimages. They can dynamically produce images for your emails. http://niftyimages.com/